# How to make installer .run application

Tags: java, linux, apache, postgresql

Here's my idea:
I developed a web J2EE application,

This application needs some prerequisites for it to work (JDK 7, PostgreSQL, httpd ...).

My goal is to make this application installs automatically with all the prerequisites (JDK 7, PostgreSQL, httpd ...) in linux. like executable .exe in windows or mac OSX .dmg

Do you know to do it Any Way or idea?

Tks a lot.

Abdelali

Comment: Bundle it together and write a script to install together...

Comment: hello, i write all scripts for this auto install and configure for PostgreSQL,JDK,Tomcat ... i need a graphical interface installer

Comment: @AbdelaliElkouri in that case http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to ask.